# Center text align of 'MDL - Side Drawer Menu' not working properly.(getmdl.io)

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm currently using a built-in **navigation** layout of **Material Design Lite**. I'm giving the description link so that you can understand: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section.
I'm trying to make center-aligned title of **mdl side drawer menu**. But it's not working properly. I tried hard to fix it, but didn't find any solution:
At first, I'm providing a screenshot of my work:
[image]

The html code:

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title"><a href="{{ url('/') }}">iPortal</a></span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Customized CSS:

```
.mdl-layout__drawer .mdl-layout-title{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work properly

```
.mdl-layout__drawer .mdl-layout-title{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```